# How to setup an un-conventional foreign key relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6.1.1 Code First against an existing schema which I can’t change.  I have a one to many relationship between `Visit` and `VisitActivityLog`.

```
public class Visit
{
    public Guid VisitKey { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VisitActivityLog> VisitActivityLogs { get; set; }
}

public class VisitActivityLog
{
    public Guid LogKey { get; set; }
    public Guid VisitKey { get; set; }
    public Visit Visit { get; set; }
}

public class VisitConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Visit>
{
    public VisitConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Visits");
        HasKey(visit => visit.VisitKey);
    }
}

public class VisitActivityLogConfiruration : EntityTypeConfiguration<VisitActivityLog>
{
    public VisitActivityLogConfiruration()
    {
        ToTable("VisitsActivityLog");
        HasKey(log => log.LogKey);
        HasRequired(log => log.Visit).WithMany().HasForeignKey(log => log.VisitKey);
    }
}
```

When I try to query visits I get the following exception:

```
SqlException: Invalid column name 'Visit_VisitKey'.Invalid column name 'Visit_VisitKey'.
```

This is the generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project2].[VisitKey] AS [VisitKey], 
    [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project2].[LogKey] AS [LogKey], 
    [Project2].[VisitKey1] AS [VisitKey1], 
    [Project2].[Visit_VisitKey] AS [Visit_VisitKey]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Limit1].[VisitKey] AS [VisitKey], 
        [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Extent2].[LogKey] AS [LogKey], 
        [Extent2].[VisitKey] AS [VisitKey1], 
        [Extent2].[Visit_VisitKey] AS [Visit_VisitKey], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[LogKey] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (100) 
            [Extent1].[VisitKey] AS [VisitKey], 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Visits] AS [Extent1] ) AS [Limit1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[VisitsActivityLog] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[VisitKey] = [Extent2].[Visit_VisitKey]
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[VisitKey] ASC, [Project2].[C2] ASC
```

If I remove the `VisitActivityLogs` property from `Visit`, I can query the `VisitActivityLog` and find the `Visit` associated with it.

I have read these Microsoft docs [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh134698.aspx), but I can’t figure how to configure EF correctly.

Comment: Why do you need `public Guid VisitKey { get; set; }` in `VisitActivityLog` when you can access it via `Visit ` reference ?

Comment: It's the FK on the `VisitActivityLog` table.  I included it in the model so I can use the `.HasForeignKey()` config method.  I also tried removing it from the model and using the `.Map(m => m.MapKey("VisitKey"))`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I've got a working example with Map method, but w/o VisitKey property. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the similar issue. We solved it using .Map() method. Assuming that your foreign key is named `"VisitKey"` and after few experiments I got the following code working. The only difference is that `VisitKey` is removed from `VisitActivityLog` and foreign key config moved to `VisitConfiguration`

```
public class Visit
{
    public Guid VisitKey { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VisitActivityLog> VisitActivityLogs { get; set; }
}

public class VisitActivityLog
{
    public Guid LogKey { get; set; }
    public Visit Visit { get; set; }
}

public class VisitConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Visit>
{
    public VisitConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Visits");
        HasKey(visit => visit.VisitKey);
        HasMany(visit => visit.VisitActivityLogs)
            .WithRequired(v => v.Visit)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("VisitKey"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class VisitActivityLogConfiruration : EntityTypeConfiguration<VisitActivityLog>
{
    public VisitActivityLogConfiruration()
    {
        ToTable("VisitsActivityLog");
        HasKey(log => log.LogKey);
    }
}
```